# Varnish Error: Failed to open (any) accept sockets

Tags: docker, varnish, ulimit

I am trying to restart *varnish* service in vagrant container `sudo /etc/init.d/varnish restart` and it throws those errors:

```
/etc/init.d/varnish: 36: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
/etc/init.d/varnish: 36: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
[FAIL] Stopping HTTP accelerator: varnishd failed!
/etc/init.d/varnish: 36: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
[FAIL] Starting HTTP accelerator: varnishd failed!
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
bind(): Address already in use
Error: Failed to open (any) accept sockets.
```

I checked line 36:

```
# Open files (usually 1024, which is way too small for varnish)
ulimit -n ${NFILES:-131072}

# Maxiumum locked memory size for shared memory log
ulimit -l ${MEMLOCK:-82000}
```

Any suggestions how to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused when I upgraded docker and some how some other process kept still working from the last container.

```
sudo killall nginx
```

and

```
sudo killall varnish
```

and start the services again, has
solved the problem